# returning a class from a metod gives wrong values for class variables

Tags: c++, c++11, c++14

My header file contains a class that holds a Boolean and a string

```
#ifndef RESULT_P
#define RESULT_P

#include <string>
#include <utility>

class MyResult {

public:
    MyResult() = default;
    MyResult( const bool& ok, std::string  msg) : ok_(ok), msg_(std::move(msg)) {}
    explicit MyResult(bool ok) : ok_(ok) {}
    explicit MyResult(std::string msg) : ok_(false), msg_(std::move(msg)) {}

    bool ok() const {
        return ok_;
    }

    void ok(bool ok) {
        ok_ = ok;
    }

    const std::string &msg() const {
        return msg_;
    }

    void msg(const std::string &msg) {
        msg_ = msg;
    }

private:
    bool ok_ { false };
    std::string msg_;

};

#endif
```

I am using the MyResult(std::string) constructor to create a result that takes by default false on the ok_ method variable.

I am calling

> auto result = do_something()

The method do somethings looks like this

```
   MyResult do_something() {

      if ( something ) {
         //code    } else {
          return MyResult("something wrong happened");    
      }
    }
```

So returns false and a string. When this method returns and I am calling

```
cout << result.ok() << endl;
```

it prints true!!! instead of false. What is wrong?

UPDATE: sorry for my initial version of the post. It prints true, not false.

Comment: why you think it would be `true`?

Comment: `true` isn't anywhere to be found in your code.

Comment: Please try to create a proper [mcve] to show us, one that replicates the behavior and which we ourselves can copy-paste to try.

Comment: Your `do_something` function seems to fail to return anything if `something` is `false`.  Undefined behavior, or you better post *real* code.

Comment: `MyResult("something wrong happened")` calls the `bool` constructor. Since the pointer to a string literal is never `nullptr` when it is implicitly converted to `bool` it produces `true`. See the duplicate.

Comment: sorry about the confusion, the result.ok() returns true!

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux, got u thanks. It answers my question.

Answer (score 1):

Using `MyResult("something wrong happened");` you are calling this ctor `explicit MyResult(std::string msg) : ok_(false), msg_(std::move(msg)) {}` then ok_ field is initialized as false.

Comment: This is incorrect. `MyResult("something wrong happened");` calls the `explicit MyResult(bool)` constructor. See the duplicate.